# SectionList creating a separate renderItem for each character of a string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to use a SectionList to print the key/value pairs of an object. However, values which are strings are rendered character by character by the renderItem.

Code:

```
const mainObject = {
 "key1": "val1",
 "key2": ["val2.0","val2.1"],
 "key3": "val3",
}

const renderItem = ({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>

const sectionHeader = ({section}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{section.title}</Text>);

//Object.entries(obj) returns an array [["key0","value0"],["key1","value1"]
//for all the key value pairs in the object

const sections = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).map((val) => ({
    data: val[1],
    title: val[0],
}))


const ObjectList = props => (
    <SectionList
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={sectionHeader}
        sections={sections(mainObject)}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    >
    </SectionList>
)
```

The output on the screen is:

```
key1
v
a
l
1

key2
val2.0
val2.1

key3
v
a
l
3
```

To fix the problem, I have put the strings into Arrays and so Strings inside arrays are printed properly, but I was just wondering why they need to be nested inside an array for the whole string to be printed on on one row?

```
const sections = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).map((val) => ({

    //checks if the value is an array, if not then nest that value
    //inside the array otherwise leave it as it is

    data: !Array.isArray(val[1]) ? [val[1]] : val[1],
    title: val[0],
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` key in the `sections` prop is expected to be a list of items to render in the `section`. Your code above ends up with something like:

```
const sections = [
  {title: 'key1': data: 'val1'},
  ...
]
```

when `val[1]` is a string.

So the `SectionList` is iterating over `data`, which is just a string, to create each item under that section heading, hence you get each character. If `val[1]` may be a string or may be an array of strings then you're doing the correct thing by wrapping it in an array if necessary.

If you have control over how `mainObject` is created you probably want to wrap the vals beforehand:

```
const mainObject = {
 "key1": ["val1"],
 "key2": ["val2.0","val2.1"],
 "key3": ["val3"],
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have went over the docs couple of times and can't believe i missed that detail.